# How do I input a value into a Shiny DataTable based on a user click?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

My example is based on code from Stéphane Laurent with my code below: [Change row CSS properties on clicking an icon](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTcallbacks.html#change-row-css-properties-on-clicking-an-icon)

My goal in addition to changing the CSS properties is to add today's date to the corresponding row where the click was made.

So far I've created an extra column called *the_date*, created a reactiveValues dataframe, and then updated it based on an observeEvent. When the "x" is clicked the *the_date* gets filled, but it takes another click to change the CSS properties. If I then click on another "x" without a *the_date* value, then the CSS properties change for the whole table.

**How do I change the CSS properties on a click and also edit the table at the same time?**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
rowNames <- TRUE # whether to show row names in the table
colIndex <- as.integer(rowNames)
callback <- c(
  sprintf("table.on('click', 'td:nth-child(%d)', function(){", colIndex+1),
  "  var td = this;",
  "  var cell = table.cell(td);",
  "  if(cell.data() === 'ok'){",
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "  } else {",
  "    cell.data('ok');",
  "  }",
  "  var $row = $(td).closest('tr');",
  "  $row.toggleClass('excluded');",
  "  var excludedRows = [];",
  "  table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "    if($(this).hasClass('excluded')){",
  "      excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id').split('_')[1]))",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "})"
)
restore <- c(
  "function(e, table, node, config) {",
  "  table.$('tr').removeClass('excluded').each(function(){",
  sprintf("    var td = $(this).find('td').eq(%d)[0];", colIndex),
  "    var cell = table.cell(td);",
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
  "}"
)
render <- c(
  'function(data, type, row, meta){',
  '  if(type === "display"){',
  '    var color = data === "remove" ? "red" : "forestgreen";',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:" + color +',
  '           "; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-" +',
  '           data + "\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  } else {',
  '    return data;',
  '  }',
  '}'
)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".excluded { color: rgb(211,211,211); font-style: italic; }"
    ))
  ),

  br(),
  DTOutput("mytable")
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  mcars <- mtcars[1:6,]
  mcars[,"the_date"] <- ""
  df <- cbind(Selected = "remove", mcars, id = paste0("row_",1:6))

  RV <- reactiveValues(data = df)


  output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(isolate(RV$data), rownames = rowNames,
              extensions = c("Select", "Buttons"),
              selection = "none",
              callback = JS(callback),
              options = list(
                scrollY = "400px",
                paging = FALSE,
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(df){return df[%d];}",
                                   ncol(df)-1+colIndex)),
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(df)-1+colIndex),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                  list(className = "notselectable", targets = colIndex),
                  list(targets = colIndex, render = JS(render))
                ),
                dom = "Bt",
                buttons = list("copy", "csv",
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Select all rows',
                                 action = JS(restore)
                               )
                ),
                select = list(style = "single",
                              selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
              )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)


  observeEvent(input$excludedRows, {
    RV$data[as.integer(input$excludedRows), ]$the_date <- as.character.Date(today())
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

rowNames <- TRUE # whether to show row names in the table
colIndex <- as.integer(rowNames)

mcars <- mtcars[1:6,]
mcars[,"the_date"] <- ""
df <- cbind(Selected = "remove", mcars, id = paste0("row_",1:6))
colDate <- which(names(df) == "the_date")

callback <- c(
  sprintf("table.on('click', 'td:nth-child(%d)', function(){", colIndex+1),
  "  var td = this;",
  "  var cell = table.cell(td);",
  "  var $row = $(td).closest('tr');",
  sprintf("  var cell_date = table.cell($row[0], %d);", colDate + colIndex - 1),
  "  var today = new Date();",
  "  var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();",
  "  if(cell.data() === 'ok'){",
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "    cell_date.data('');",
  "  } else {",
  "    cell.data('ok');",
  "    cell_date.data(date);",
  "  }",
  "  $row.toggleClass('excluded');",
  "  var excludedRows = [];",
  "  table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "    if($(this).hasClass('excluded')){",
  "      excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id').split('_')[1]))",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "})"
)
restore <- c(
  "function(e, table, node, config) {",
  "  table.$('tr').removeClass('excluded').each(function(){",
  sprintf("    var td = $(this).find('td').eq(%d)[0];", colIndex),
  "    var cell = table.cell(td);",
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
  "}"
)
render <- c(
  'function(data, type, row, meta){',
  '  if(type === "display"){',
  '    var color = data === "remove" ? "red" : "forestgreen";',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:" + color +',
  '           "; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-" +',
  '           data + "\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  } else {',
  '    return data;',
  '  }',
  '}'
)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".excluded { color: rgb(211,211,211); font-style: italic; }"
    ))
  ),

  br(),
  DTOutput("mytable")
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(df, rownames = rowNames,
              extensions = c("Select", "Buttons"),
              selection = "none",
              callback = JS(callback),
              options = list(
                scrollY = "400px",
                paging = FALSE,
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(df){return df[%d];}",
                                   ncol(df)-1+colIndex)),
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(df)-1+colIndex),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                  list(className = "notselectable", targets = colIndex),
                  list(targets = colIndex, render = JS(render))
                ),
                dom = "Bt",
                buttons = list("copy", "csv",
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Select all rows',
                                 action = JS(restore)
                               )
                ),
                select = list(style = "single",
                              selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
              )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Is there a way to save the rows that are checked so that if I revisit my app all the rows aren't unchecked?